# Apache Flink: How to store intermedia data in streaming application

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am implementing the MisraGries algorithm with Flink's DataStream API. It keeps `k` counters to record the data summary by increment or decrement.

What is the best approach to store such counters when using DataStream API to implement the algorithm? Now I just declared a `HashMap` variable in the operator. Is this the right approach or do I need to use some other features like state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the counters in Flink's managed state, i.e., either [keyed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#keyed-state) or [operator state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#operator-state) and [enable checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html). Otherwise, the information will be lost in case of a failure.

If state is correctly used and checkpointing is enabled, Flink periodically checkpoints the state of an application. In case of a failure, the job is restarted and its state is reset to the latest checkpoint.